# What is GenericFacesPortlet in JSF portlet bridge?

Tags: java, jsf, portlet

What is [GenericFacesPortlet](http://myfaces.apache.org/portlet-bridge/api/apidocs/javax/portlet/faces/GenericFacesPortlet.html) in JSF portlet bridge? Is it a Portlet or Portlet Bridge?

Comment: What part of [the documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/portlet-bridge/api/apidocs/javax/portlet/faces/GenericFacesPortlet.html) is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

The JSF portlet bridge provides implementations of the technology needed to expose a JSF application as a portlet within a Portlet 2.0 or Portlet 1.0 environment. (see [JSR 301](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=301))

It is provided to simplify the development of portlets based on the JSF portlet bridge. If all requests are handled by the bridge you don't have to subclass GenericFacesPortlet. Just use it in your portlet.xml, example:

```
<portlet>
   <portlet-name>FacesTestPortlet</portlet-name>
   <portlet-class>
      javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet
   </portlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
      <value>/pages/test.xhtml</value>
   </init-param>
   <supports>
      <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
      <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
   </supports>
   <portlet-info>
      <title>Faces test Portlet</title>
   </portlet-info>
</portlet>
```